# IQueryable for Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, anonymous-types

I use EntityFramework, I'm querying and returning partial data using Anonymous Types. Currently I'm using `IQueryable<dynamic>`, it works, but I would like to know if this is the proper way to do it or if there is some other returning datatype that I'm not aware of.

```
public IQueryable<dynamic> FindUpcomingEventsCustom(int daysFuture)
{
    DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime dateTimeFuture = dateTimeNow.AddDays(daysFuture);
    return db.EventCustoms.Where(x => x.DataTimeStart > dateTimeNow & x.DataTimeStart <= dateTimeFuture)
        .Select(y => new { y.EventId, y.EventTitle, y.DataTimeStart});
}
```

Comment: What is the problem the `IQueryable` or the `dynamic` part of the return type?

Comment: hi nemesv, no problem, I would like to know more about c# and anonymous type for this reason I'm asking. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normally, you use anonymous types only inside the scope of one method. You don't return anonymous types to the caller. If that's what you want to do, you should create a class and return that:

```
public class Event
{
    private readonly int _eventId;
    private readonly string _eventTitle;
    private readonly DateTime _dateTimeStart;

    public Event(int eventId, string eventTitle, DateTime dateTimeStart)
    {
        _eventId = eventId;
        _eventTitle = eventTitle;
        _dateTimeStart = dateTimeStart;
    }

    public int EventId { get { return _eventId; } }
    public string EventTitle { get { return _eventTitle; } }
    public DateTime DateTimeStart{ get { return _dateTimeStart; } }
}



public IQueryable<Event> FindUpcomingEventsCustom(int daysFuture) 
{ 
    DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow; 
    DateTime dateTimeFuture = dateTimeNow.AddDays(daysFuture); 
    return db.EventCustoms
             .Where(x => x.DataTimeStart > dateTimeNow
                         && x.DataTimeStart <= dateTimeFuture) 
             .Select(y => new Event(y.EventId, y.EventTitle, y.DataTimeStart)); 
}
```

Comment: I was thinking to returning anonymous type as the result of the action is JSON

Comment: @GibboK: I am not sure I follow. I don't see an "action" or JSON here

Comment: yes I have not uploaded the full code, thanks for your answer