# Trying to pass back the results of a LINQ query from a middle tier class

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

I need some help with this feature...

The first query works fine:

```
public List<Project> GetProjectByCustomerID(Int16 customerid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    IEnumerable<Project> project = DbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.CustomerID == customerid);

                    List<Project> myProjects = new List<Project>();

                    myProjects = project.ToList();

                    return myProjects;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

The second query has my Project List and I want to bring back only certain columns in the query, but is giving me the error: "Cannot convert type IQueryable Anonymoustype#1 to Generic.List". The design time compile error is on the entire SQL statement right before the "(s =>"

```
public List<Project> GetProjectByCustomerID(Int16 customerid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    List<Project> myProjects = new List<Project>();

                    myProjects = DbContext.Projects.Include("TimeTrackings").Where(p => p.CustomerID == customerid && p.Category.CategoryID == 5 && p.Customer.City == "NY" && p.Status.StatusID == 1 && p.Priority.PriorityID == 2).Select(s => new
                    {
                        pridesc = s.Priority.Description,
                        s.Notes,
                        stadesc = s.Status.Description
                    });

                    return myProjects;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

The third query allows me to select the columns I need. The whole query is fine, except I can't pass back the "project" variable. I get a design time compile error of: "Cannot convert type Generic.List.AnonymousType#1 to Generic.List "

```
public List<String> GetProjectByCustomerID(Int16 customerid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    var project = DbContext.Projects.Include("TimeTrackings").Where(p => p.CustomerID == customerid && p.Category.CategoryID == 5 && p.Customer.City == "NY" && p.Status.StatusID == 1 && p.Priority.PriorityID == 2).Select(s => new
                    {
                        pridesc = s.Priority.Description,
                        s.Notes,
                        stadesc = s.Status.Description
                    }).ToList();

                    return project;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

**What is the correct way (syntax wise as well) to pass back the second and third queries?**

I know I can do the third query right in the code-behind and bind it to the grid with the "var" variable as the datasource. However, **I would appreciate it very much if someone can inform me how I can successfully pass back the second and third query types to the front end from a middle tier class.**

Answer (score 4):

You're creating anonymous types in your `Select` methods, not `string`s or `Project`s.  The first query works because you're returning a `List<Project>`.

If you don't want the entire project, but only a subset of fields, create a new class that holds only the fields you need, and use that in your `Select()` instead of creating an anonymous type.  For an illustration of the technique, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11982959/102937).

Comment: I tried to put an edit thru last Friday, but didn't go thru. If you can please vote for the edit in order to display it, it will show the error that I'm getting when I try this technique and therefore, eventually solve the error via your feedback. Please vote for the edit.